# Deriving another formula for least square

Tags: linear-algebra

In a proof of a theorem in [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/mazumder10a.pdf)(page 26), they started with what is shown below

[image]

The $\|\cdot\|_*$ is the trace norm and I do understand SVD decomposition but I don't understand how they decompose $||Z-W||_F^2$ to what is between brackets?

Comment: I think the $\|Z\|_F^2$ should be $\|W\|_F^2$.

Comment: @angryavian it is possible it is a typo since they drop "$||Z||_F^2$" as it does not depend on $\tilde{d}, \tilde{u}, \tilde{v}$'s when they want to minimize with respect to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Frobenius norm is induced by the inner product $\langle A, B\rangle_F := \text{Tr}(A'B)$ (where $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$), in the sense that $\|A\|_F^2 = \langle A, A \rangle_F$.
- A useful fact is that if $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices of the appropriate dimension, then $\|UAV\|_F = \|A\|_F$. You can prove this easily using the above inner product formulation of the Frobenius norm.

You can show that

$$\|Z-W\|_F^2 = \|Z\|_F^2 - 2 \langle Z, W \rangle_F + \|W\|_F^2.$$

- Note that $\|Z\|_F^2 = \|D\|_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2$.
- Note that $\langle Z, W\rangle_F = \langle UDV', W \rangle_F
  = \text{Tr}(VD'U'W) = \text{Tr}(D'U'WV)$. Think through the definition of trace and matrix multiplication to show that this equals $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i u_i' W v_i$.
- After correcting the typo in the paper ($\|Z\|_F^2$ should be $\|W\|^2_F$), this leads to the desired expression in the paper.